# Concrete example of functional knowledge allowing you to write better imperative/OO code

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I've been working with functional programming for a while now and I think it's great so I would like to teach some of my friends Haskell.

Unfortunately, I can't think of any particular piece of code to show them and say "See, this is how it would look imperatively, see how much better functional is"

So, could someone that's more of an expert than I am (and that's a very low requirement) help me out?

This doesn't seem to oppinionated to me, but in case it is, please tell me how to fix it.

Comment: It's not a matter of applying the same exact techniques or translate functional into imperative code. It's more like a matter of exercising your mind and attitude towards problem solving by thinking and writing with more concise languages. But this is just my (biased) opinion.

Comment: @Riccardo Sure, but I'm sure you've heard the claim that learning functional programming lets your write better code even when not using strictly functional languages. Surely there have to be some examples. Even if it's just something that you wouldn't think of if it weren't for functional programming.

Comment: Using more immutability is one example.

Comment: I started learning Scala recently because I asked myself a similar question. [This book](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/index.html) highlights how functional ideas help write better OO code.

Comment: You can sure demonstrate how much nicer many standard algorithms come out. And specifically in Haskell, quite a good argument is how much more powerful the type signatures become, allowing for [a search engine that lets you describe what you want a library function _to do_, without needing to know any common name for it.](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=hoogle).

Comment: This is not at all concrete, but I've found myself writing more compositional code also when coding in entirely imperative languages after learning Haskell. I'm thinking more in terms of "the function I need is the result of applying these other functions in turn, so let's write and test each one on its own."

Comment: This question is not opinion based as long as the answers provide *concrete* examples, as required by the question. I voted for reopening it.

Answer (score 7):

Probably the best notions to carry back are so called "value semantics" and "purity".

Each of these play off one another so much it's hard to separate them in practice. In principle, however, *value semantics* means that each "thing" should act like a value instead of an object. It leads to simpler passing, less "spooky action at a distance" from statefulness, and it provides some amount of background to perform equational reasoning on code. *Purity* means that side effects do not occur wherever you have code but instead only at carefully demarcated points. This means that most of your code ends up independent and reusable while only the core "application" bits entangle themselves deeply with state and effect.

You might say that purity is having value semantics everywhere or that values are pure computations—so perhaps it's worth saying that "values" refer to the nouns (statics) of your system and "purity" the verbs (dynamics).

---

These techniques are well known to be useful in other languages. It's a common idea in OO languages these days to happily sacrifice some speed for value semantics due to the organizational and correctness benefits. If you become comfortable with Haskell then you will understand how value semantics and purity work if they are applied to every single aspect of an entire program without compromise. That means you've been exposed to some powerful patterns for reasoning about and building pure programs.

One place I've been thinking about making a comparison is between free monads and the Command pattern. Both are solving very similar problems—"how do I make explicit a structure containing instructions to be performed by a program and execute it at a later time, perhaps in various ways?"—but the Command pattern tends to dance around a lot mutability in, at the very least, the interpreter if not the commands themselves.

Can we write Command patterns which behave more like Free monads? What would be the benefits? These are the kinds of questions you can ask with much more acuity if you've got a strong Haskell background.

Comment: On the first part: the main way Haskell has improved my C# was by teaching me not to add any more state than strictly necessary.

Answer (score 6):

It's an interesting, and tricky question. There has been a trend of concepts from functional languages making their way into imperative languages for some time now, and the line between functional/imperative languages is quite blurred. For example, say you want to square every element of a list `xs` and store the result in a new list, `ys`.

```python
>> xs = [1, 2, 3]                   #  Python
```

```
>> xs = [1, 2, 3]                   -- Haskell
```

If you didn't know about functional idioms, you might do this:

```python
>> ys = [0] * len(xs)               #  Python
>> for i in range(len(xs)):
       ys[i] = xs[i] * xs[i]
```

In Haskell you would just write

```
>> ys = map (\x -> x * x) xs        -- Haskell
```

This idiom also exists in Python, of course

```python
>> ys = map(lambda x: x * x, xs)    #  Python
```

Arguably, an even nicer way to write it is using a list comprehension

```
>> ys = [x * x | x <- xs]           -- Haskell
```

which also exists in Python

```python
>> ys = [x * x for x in xs]         #  Python
```

Certainly, the functional way is much nicer (and more composable, more reusable) than the imperative way. But in this case, you don't need to use a functional language to get the benefit - you just have to be ready to "think in a functional way."

Comment: if your friend knows matlab, this is not convincing, since he can do `xs.^2`, while Matlab is not a functional language.

Comment: @ahala: Matlab has much a Pearl-approach to this stuff: many people would like to do that specific thing, so let's mess up our entire syntax specification to allow this special case to work "easily". Which is obviously adverse to many programming principles recognised not only by functional, but also by OO programmers. There's a nice [rant on such languages, Matlab in particular, by Henning Thielemann](http://www.parallelnetz.de/ScriptingHater.html).

Comment: @leftroundabout Thanks for that link. Reading it via Google Translate was a bit like reading an essay on programming languages by Chaucer.

Comment: It's particularly fun that the code is translated as well, so that `0,001` is "translated" to `0.001`, which completely breaks the section about the comma operator...

Comment: @ChrisTaylor: The iterative Python code doesn't work because you can't assign to elements of `y` that don't exist.  You could try something like `ys = [0] * len(xs)` or `ys.append(xs[i] * xs[i])` instead.

Comment: @ahala: `xs .^ i = fmap (^ i) xs`

Comment: @TomEllis Thanks! Been writing Matlab for too long ;)

Comment: @ahala That particular Matlab idiom is borrowed from array-based languages (APL, J, Fortran) rather than imperative languages. Array-based languages have a lot in common with functional languages. Also, who says Matlab isn't a functional language..?!

Answer (score 2):

Monads and continuations.

I have come across code like this:

```
synchronized(q) {
  Object o = q.poll();
  if (o == null) {
    ...// do something
  }
}
```

This has folded itself into a much nicer API refactoring:

```
Object o = q.poll(doSomethingAsLambda)
```

The `q` implementation was rewritten, of course, but now synchronization is finer grained, because the implementation permits executing custom code "inside" a branch the `q` implementation would be aware of.

Answer (score 2):

Modern functional languages (like Haskell and ML) are concise - you can say a lot in not much code.

A real benefit of concision is that you can iterate a design quickly, and in other domains (like graphic or fashion design) rapid iteration seems to be considered to be one of the "tools" for becoming a good or expert designer; therefore it's a fair belief that learning how to rapidly iterate software designs will help make you a better programmer.

Of course modern scripting languages like Python and "design" languages like Alloy (developed by Daniel Jackson at the MIT) are concise and allow you to rapidly iterate designs / prototypes. So a greater theme seems to be that "lightweight" / concise languages help you iterate and improve your design skills rather than just "functional programming will make you a better 'mainstream' programmer".